FHIR search with occurrence parameter fails for Timing
I'm trying to find all ServiceRequests (in my Azure FHIR Service instance) that end before a given date. Some of my ServiceRequests.occurrence have a Timing instance and others have a dateTime instance. When searching with the "occurrence=eb{date}" the search doesn't pick up the ServiceRequests with a Timing instance. The search works fine for ServiceRequests with a dateTime instance.
Any idea what the issue might be with my search query?
For example, if I perform this search without the occurrence parameter:
{{fhirurl}}/ServiceRequest

I get the following result:
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    ...
    "entry": [
        {
            "fullUrl": ...,
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "ServiceRequest",
                ...
                "occurrenceTiming": {
                    "repeat": {
                        "boundsPeriod": {
                            "start": "2024-08-27T08:00:00+02:00",
                            "end": "2024-09-10T07:59:59+02:00"
                        },
                        ...
                    }
                },
                ...
            },
            ...
        },
        {
            "fullUrl": ...,
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "ServiceRequest",
                ...
                "occurrenceDateTime": "2024-08-27T08:00:00+02:00",
                ...
            },
            ...
        }
    ]
}

But when I add the occurrence parameter
{{fhirurl}}/ServiceRequest?occurrence=eb2024-09-13

The search comes back without the instance that has a Timing instance:
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    ...
    "entry": [
        {
            "fullUrl": ...,
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "ServiceRequest",
                ...
                "occurrenceDateTime": "2024-08-27T08:00:00+02:00",
                ...
            },
            ...
        },
    ]
}

Any idea what the issue might be?
I've also tried using "le" and "lt" instead of "eb" as a date prefix, without success.

I do not like/believe-in "past the same issue everywhere in the internet"..but in this case, consider posting to https://github.com/microsoft/fhir-server/issues      (you might want to pull the code, wire it up to a sql-server-instance (use docker for a quick way to stand up a sql-server instance) .. to make sure you get the same issue.  I reported a Human.GivenName (specifying many given-names) and the team responded fairly quickly to that issue.  If you get resolution there, then please follow up here as well for future internet searchers.
